# VS code, django project have template errors, how to avoid them?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have use autopep8 to check my Python error & warning in VS Code, and config the "Go to Next Problem in Files" to fast jump to the next one.

[image: go to next problem shortcut.]

One day, I added one html file, found that the error list is long.

[image: Found html warning.]

I do not care the html's error, cuz it is just test files. How can I avoid them?

Answer (score 2):

You could head to the **settings.json** and add this which will ignore validations in HTML files:

```
"html.validate.scripts": false,
```

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution is that disable the HTML>Validate. Then the errors just from Python.

[image: settings]